# How to prevent WebKit2.WebView from auto scrolling to the top after set_zoom_level()?

Tags: python, gtk, webkit

I am building a Python GTK application and I need zoom in/out the webview.
I connected on_button_clicked signal to the callback:

```
self.webview1.set_zoom_level(self.webview1.get_zoom_level() - 0.1)
```

When I clicked the button the page zoomed but it auto scroll to the top.
How to prevent the page from auto scrolling ?